# Dynamic location path SQL external table

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, path

what I tried to do, is to receive data via Azure Synapse from a Data Lake and export it to another Data Lake. This transfer already works. The problem I'm having is that when I want to store a second set of data within the same location. I received the error of "External table location already exists."
My first try was to fetch the already stored data join it with the new set and store it back to my container within the Data Lake. Unfortunately I received the same error.
Therefore I wanted to store my (daily) new sets of data in separate directories. As name for those directories I would like to use a timestamp.
My statement:

```
DECLARE @timestamp varchar(42);
SET @timestamp = CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME());
DECLARE @path varchar(42);
SET @path = CONCAT ( '/myMainFolder/' , @timestamp , '/');
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE export
WITH ( LOCATION = @path
    ,DATA_SORUCE = [historicalexport]
    ,FILE_FORMAT = MY_CSV
    )
AS
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM dbo.anExternalTable
```

Executing this will bring up an error due to "Incorrect syntax near '@path'." But why? Anybody any idea?
When printing out @path it is exactly as I want it to be, with no spaces etc… @path = '/myMainFolder/TODAYSDATE/'

Thanks for your help in advance!
Thomas

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Sorry, still a nope. We implemented a workaround and from time to time someone new tries to get it done. No success so far...

Comment: I actually ended up raising this with MS directly and they basically said this is by design and that you need to delete the underlying files in the Data Lake before you can CETAS again to that location and that using a dynamic path just isn't supported at present.  My workaround was to create a Data Factory pipeline that can be called, which dynamically deletes the Data Lake files and then executes a Stored Procedure based on a given table name.  Hella clunky, but works in my case as the whole process is automated.

Comment: I'm facing same issue, anyone has found a solution for this?

Comment: @SalvatoreNedia I posted an answer hopefully it helps you

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic location is failing, because it needs to be surrounded by quotes ('). The way I solved my issue was by add the quotes around the @path. The quotes also have to be escaped.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE export
(
    column varchar(20)
)  
WITH ( 
    LOCATION = ''''@path''''
    ,DATA_SORUCE = [historicalexport]
    ,FILE_FORMAT = MY_CSV
)
```

I used something similar to this and it worked for me. Play around with the number of quotes you need. I used three because I was using dynamic sql. Hope it helps. Try

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, it worked for me.

```
DECLARE @timestamp varchar(42);
SET @timestamp = CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME());
DECLARE @path varchar(42);
--SET @path = CONCAT ( '/myMainFolder/' , @timestamp , '/');
DECLARE @QUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @QUERY ='
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE export
WITH ( LOCATION = ''/myMainFolder/'+@timestamp+'/''
    ,DATA_SORUCE = [historicalexport]
    ,FILE_FORMAT = MY_CSV
    )'
EXECUTE (@QUERY)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).